# There is a way to query the first coincidence in DB2?

Tags: sql, db2

The table I'm trying to fetch has several numbers of *Vendors* with coincidences, so I am trying to fetch clean and get one.

for example:

```
MyVendorSA CV
MyVendo SA
MyVendorsSACV
```

what i want to achieve with this is just have 1 record

the output i was looking for is: ** MyVendor **

Comment: Please add sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: @RaulGuerrero . . . Your examples don't have any duplicates (according to the SQL definition), so I don't understand the question.

Comment: How do you know `'MyVendorSA CV'` and `'MyVendo SA'` are "duplicates"?  What allows you to collapse them?  Also, there's no such thing as "first" in SQL - you have to provide some criteria (which normally turns this into some form of [tag:greatest-n-per-group] query).

Comment: No,  i wrote bad, i mean  i want to remove all **coincidences** and just have one record for each "vendor" in the table "vendors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use soundex to match similar sounding names and use row_number olap function to get first row from matching set.

`select vendor
from (
select vendor ,
row_number() over 
 ( partition by soundex( VENDOR ) ) as rn1
from VENDORSTABLE ) T
where rn1 = 1`

Comment: Thank you! i made with a subweury and i get the MAX value from the ID Vendor, i tried your query and works too!!!!  thank you